# Using UIImagePickerController to retrieve selected Image in photo Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I have a little problem using UIImagePickerController... I would like to use the image selected by user from the iPhone library and use it when instantiating my viewController:

first the User has to click on the StartWithImage button :

```
-(IBAction)startWithImage:(UIButton *) sender
{
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
    //UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    photo =(UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //code for starting game
}
```

this is how I instantiate my viewController :

```
imageSliderViewController = [[ImageSliderViewController alloc] initWithSize:colMax :rowMax:photo];
```

My view controller uses photo in the viewDidLoad like this :

```
CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(photo.CGImage, CGRectMake(ox, oy, width-1, height-1));//-1 for block effect
```

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error...

Comment: is there a backtrace or stack listing for your "`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`" error?

Comment: I'm kind of a huge beginner... how do I check for that? I'm not very good with Xcode

Comment: when it crashes, you might have an output window (if you don't see it, click under the "View" menu in Xcode and you'll see a "Debug" sub-menu.  Click "Activate Console" under that.  Then, when the crash happens, you'll see a "`(lldb)`" prompt.  Type in the command "`bt`" (without the quotes) and you should see where the crash actually happened.

Comment: There's nothing in the console other than the usual paragraph fallowed by (gdb) :


GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug 15 16:03:10 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 313.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Well, EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually happens when object was released and we somewhere try to access to this object.

try this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    //UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    photo =(UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //code for starting game

    // dismiss controller after working with it
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
}
```